# Let $f \in L(E)$ show $lim_{n\to\infty}nm({|f|>n})=0$,m()is measure

Tags: real-analysis

I prove it by this way but I don't think that's correct
:Since $f\in L(E), |f|\in L(E),lim_{n\to\infty}m({|f|\gt n})=0,lim_{n\to\infty}nm({|f|\gt n})=0$
Is that right?

Comment: The fact that $m(\lvert f\rvert > n)\to0$ does not imply that $n\cdot m(\lvert f\rvert > n)\to0$; after all, $n\to\infty$.  So, more work is required.

Comment: @Nick Peterson Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hint.

Start by letting
$$
g_n(x):=\lvert f(x)\rvert\cdot 1_{\lvert f\rvert\leq n}(x),\qquad h_n(x):=\lvert f(x)\rvert\cdot 1_{\lvert f\rvert\leq n}(x)+n\cdot 1_{\lvert f\rvert>n}.
$$
Note that both $(g_n)$ and $(h_n)$ increase pointwise to $\lvert f\rvert$.  So, by the Monotone Convergence Theorem,
$$
\int g_n\,dm\to\int\lvert f\rvert\,dm\qquad\text{and}\qquad\int h_n\,dm\to\int\lvert f\rvert\,dm
$$
as $n\to\infty$.

How can you relate these two integrals to the quantity $n\,m(\lvert f\rvert>n)$?

Comment: May I ask you what is $1_{\lvert f\rvert\leq n}(x)$ mean?

Comment: Ah, sorry.  That's the indicator function -- so, $1_A(x)$ is $1$ if $x$ satisfies $A$, and $0$ otherwise.  This particular notation is more often used in probability; you might have seen it referred to as $\chi_{\lvert f\vert>n}$ instead, and called the characteristic function.  (In probability, characteristic function has a different meaning.)

Comment: My pleasure!  I hope this helps.  This is a fairly common technique for proving basic inequalities in measure theory / probability; for instance, [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality)

Comment: $\int g_n\,dm - \int h_n\,dm$?

Comment: Well, I'd reverse that; $\int h_n\,dm-\int g_n\,dm=\int n\cdot 1_{\lvert f\rvert >n}\,dm=...$

Comment: $0=\int\lvert f\rvert\-\int\lvert f\rvert\=\int g_n\,dm - \int h_n\,dm = \int 1_{\lvert f\rvert\gt n}\,dm = nm{\lvert f\rvert\gt n}{$?

Comment: I think I got it!

Comment: Careful -- it isn't true that $\int\lvert f\rvert\,dm-\int\lvert f\vert\,dm=\int h_n\,dm-\int g_n\,dm$.  It is more accurate to say that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int h_n\,dm-\int g_n\,dm=\int \lvert f\rvert\,dm-\int\lvert f\rvert\,dm$.  Also, you should use $h_n-g_n$, not $g_n-h_n$.

Comment: Otherwise, however: yep, that's the way!

Comment: Oh,yes. Thank you so much. It's really help